# POST from angular 5 to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Angular 5

```
  onSubmit() {
        const goData = {
         fullName : this.RegisterForm.get('fullname').value,
        email : this.RegisterForm.get('email').value,
        userName : this.RegisterForm.get('username').value,
        password : this.RegisterForm.get('password').value
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(goData))

        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          })
        };

        this.http.post('http://localhost:7080/api/users/', goData , httpOptions)
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
          });
      }
```

Express js controller

```
module.exports.usersAddOne = function(req, res){
  console.log("Post new user");

  User
  .create({
    fullName:req.body.fullName,
    email:req.body.email,
    userName:req.body.userName,
    password:req.body.password
  }, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      console.log("Error creating user"+err);
      res
      .status(404)
      .json(err)
    }else{
      console.log("user created!", user);
      res
      .status(200)
      .json(user);
    }
  });
}
```

I am trying to post some data into node js in angular and it posts succcesfully but doest post any data that is defiend

so if i post goData then it posts blank

```
{
"_id": "5ae6f2f3912ee5b81d6df23a",
"__v": 0
},
```

but i want it to be data like
             fullName : "sam",,
            email : sam@gmail.com,
            userName : sam,
            password : ...

in node console it gives me undefined but i checked all the values they are defined and also hardcoded the data but still no result

Please Help, Thank you.

This is the console outputs

```
{"fullName":"sam","email":"sam","userName":"sam","password":"sam"}

register.component.ts:47 {__v: 0, _id: "5ae70e01ef0a592011724afa"}__v: 0_id: "5ae70e01ef0a592011724afa"__proto__: Object
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:7080/api/users/".
```

Comment: are you using bodyparser?

Comment: What can you see in your Network tab? Does the actual request payload contain the data?

Comment: I think problem in data ,send as JSON.stringify(goData)

Comment: @Curt {"fullName":"sam","email":"sam","userName":"sam","password":"sam"}:

Comment: That is the payload @Curt

Comment: @RahulBisht Yes i am using it

Comment: @shashank what is the output of console.log, does it contain all fields?

Comment: @RezaRahmati Yes it does

Comment: @shashank what is the out put of this `console.log("Post new user", req.body);`

Comment: @RezaRahmati { password:undefined, username:undefined, fullname:undefined, email:undefiend },,,,

Comment: @shashank is it after you changed content-type?

Comment: @RezaRahmati i have tried both application/json and application/urlencoded no progress :((

Comment: @shashank I delete my asnwer, please update your question and add console outputs

Comment: @RezaRahmati Done...